# jquery mobile 1.3 remote autocomplete can't select an element within the dynamically created list

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I set up an alert when I click on the class "upperUlProductSearch" but when I click on the li within the ajax created list I don't get a response.  I have also an a tag and another static ul li with the same class that when clicked does give me the alert.  I was hoping someone could help me figure out why I can't target the ajax li or the proper way to.  Thanks in advanced!!!

jquery:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#template", function() {
$( "#upperApplianceSearch" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
    if ( value && value.length > 1 ) {
        $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $.ajax({
            url: "productautocomplete.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                q: $input.val()
            }
        })
        .then( function (data) {
            $.each( data, function ( i, val ) {
                /*html += "<li><a href='#' data-role='none' value=" + val.productId + ">" + val.productName + "</a></li>";*/
                html += '<li class="upperUlProductSearch" id=' + val.productId + '>' + val.productName + '</li>';
            });
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
        });
    }
});
})

$(".upperUlProductSearch").click(function() {
alert ("helleo");
});
```

html:

```
<ul id="upperApplianceSearch" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-
corner-all ui-shadow" data-filter-theme="d" data-filter-placeholder="Find an  
appliance..." data-filter="true" data-icon="false" data-inset="true" data- 
role="listview">

<li id="41" class="upperUlProductSearch ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-f ui- 
first-child ui-last-child">Hawley</li>
</ul>

<a class="upperUlProductSearch ui-link">Hello</a>

<ul class="ui-listview" data-role="listview">
  <li class="upperUlProductSearch ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-f ui-first- child ui-last-child">Li Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try `$("ul.ui-listview > li").on("click",function(){ alert("hola!"); });`

Comment: @OmarNew2PHP Still not getting an alert.  This is driving me crazy!

Comment: `$(this).on("pageshow", function(){ the above code });` try it this way. Since its dynamically injected into the page, I assume so, not 100% sure.

Comment: @OmarNew2PHP Like this :$(this).on("pageshow", function(){$("ul.ui-listview > li").on("click",function(){ alert("hola!"); });}); I'm not getting anything, madness!

Comment: @OmarNew2PHP The last suggestion works on the static li, just not the dynamic li.

Comment: Ok last trial. Instead of `ul.listview("refresh");` add this `$("upperApplianceSearch").listview("refresh");`

Comment: @OmarNew2PHP the last suggestion did not work, but when I add $("#upperApplianceSearch").on("click", function() {
 alert ($(this).val());
}); I get a blank alert.  Getting somewhere, I hope!

Comment: You're getting closer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
$(".upperUlProductSearch").click(function() {
    alert("helleo");
});
```

with:

```
$('#upperApplianceSearch').on('click', 'li', function () {
    alert("helleo");
});
```

Comment: @andr Thanks, I just updated to jquery 1.9 and saw that .live was deprecated which worked at the time, but your answer is the correct one! Thanks again!

Comment: @Adam it's not mine :D my avatar is displayed here only because I *edited* this answer. *all* credit goes to Adan!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

1. Make a list container e.g. `<div id="product-list-container">...</div>`.
2. Re-create the list like so:

   ```
   $('#product-list-container')
       .empty()
       .html('<ul id="product-list" data-role="listview"...>'+listItems+'</ul>')
   ;

   $('#product-list').listview();
   ```

You might need to trigger re-render for the whole page too, so the last line would be:

```
    $('#page-containing-list').page();
    $('#product-list').listview();
```

I did this in one of my projects and it worked fine.

Also have a look what happens to the list in a debugger like Opera Dragonfly or Firebug. JQM adds not only extra attributes but also extra elements and might even make original elements (at which you listen for clicks) hidden or in accessible.

Comment: Is this right? .then( function (data) {
                $.each( data, function ( i, val ) {
                    /*html += "<li><a>" + val.productName + "</a></li>";*/
                    listItems += '<li value="' + val.productId + '" class="upperUlProductSearch" id=' + val.productId + '>' + val.productName + '</li>';
    });
                $('#productListContainer').empty().html('<ul id="productList" data-role="listview"...>'+listItems+'</ul>');
    $('#productList').listview();
    $('#template').page();
       $('#productList').listview();
            });

Comment: Just `.page` and `.listview`, not `.listview`, `.page`, `.listview`. And "..." should be replaced with whatever attributes you want to for the list (if you want any that is).

Comment: I gave it a quick try and Im getting the product-list-container to fill up with li items as I type, but when I click, Im not getting an alert...I could be that Im exhausted looking at this for 2 days.  Im going to take a break, but I'll get back to you tomorrow!  I really appreciate you helping with this!!!

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you don't add links in the list. that's probably it. See: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/widgets/listviews/#list-inset

Comment: no that's not the issue.  This is the solution:keep the original code and to get the alert to call I needed the code: $(".upperUlProductSearch").live("click", function() {
 alert ($(this).val());
});  Thank you again for your help, I do like your idea of making a separate list container!

Comment: Check this, Similar to @Nux. http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/about-that-jquery-mobile-trick-correction/